# Problems with FORM URL when switching to GET-method

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with creating a simple search form, used to search my database.

I started using the POST-method and everything worked fine, but switched to using GET-method instead to be able to bookmark my search results. But now I have trouble with the "action-url" when posting.

```
<form action="index.php?page=searchresult'" method="post">
```

This worked fine, I got my var's sent to the stated URL, but

```
<form action="index.php?page=searchresult" method="get">
```

Doesn't work. When I check my HTML code everything looks great, but I end up going to the URL

```
site.com/index.php?ALL THE GET-variables linedup here.
```

I am loosing the "?page=searchresult" part when using the GET-method?!

Am I missing something here, please help?!

Humble regards :)

Comment: Can you share your actual php code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GET methood then you can pass page parameter in hidden field
like

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="searchresult">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this to

```
<form action="index.php?page=searchresult" method="get">
```

Put the page element as a hidden tag.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="searchresult"/>
<!-- Rest of the input elements -->
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: As usual the answer is so obvious when you get it presented. :P Code changed, and it works, thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a quote too much, try removing it.

```
                                         |   
                                        \|/
<form action="index.php?page=searchresult'" method="post">
```

Comment: Aah, sry, just a mistype, my bad ! :(

Answer (score 0):

GET sends data in the query string. If the URL in the action has a query string, it will be overwritten by the new one generated by the form.

Store your data in hidden inputs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is interesting, but you can fix it using an hidden `<input>`, such as this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="searchresult" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Just compile the "value" of the hidden input with what you need to pass.

Tried it and it actually works.

Edit:

obviously, from php, use this:

```
<?php $page = ((isset($_GET['page'])?($_GET['page']):("nope")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden page data in the form.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="searchresult" />
```

Simply because "page=searchresult" is a get data.